# Pop up elements based on Index while creating list of lists + the item popped up

Tags: python, list, slice

I have seen already quite good answers on how to make list of lists from flat list. My problem is to pop some values before making list of lists and get the following result:

```
l = ['119', '222', '219', '293', '4', '179', '124', '500', '235', '7']

wanted_output = [['119', '222', '219', '293'], '4', ['179', '124', '500', '235'], '7']
```

So far i have tried this:

```
ll = [l[i:i+4] for i in range(0, len(l), 4)]
[['119', '222', '219', '293'], ['4', '179', '124', '500'], ['235', '7']]
```

and the result is not what i wanted. I would like to achieve every four elements to contain a list of list, the next element (which is every 4th element) to be independent and individual element, for example in this case 4 and 7 are the elements i want to get.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

```
>>> [x for i in range(0, len(l), 5) for x in (l[i:i+4], l[i+4])]
[['119', '222', '219', '293'], '4', ['179', '124', '500', '235'], '7']
```

Comment: Thanks. That was quick and did the trick of what i wanted to achieve.

Answer (score 1):

If the length of your input is divisible by 5, you can use

```
from itertools import chain

l = ['119', '222', '219', '293', '4', '179', '124', '500', '235','7']

list(chain.from_iterable((a, b) for *a, b in zip(*[iter(l)]*5)))
# [['119', '222', '219', '293'], '4', ['179', '124', '500', '235'], '7']
```

which doesn't require the input iterable to be sliceable.

Comment: This is helpful. Thanks